Multiple replacements in a long expression
Why does the replace /. not work on the second argument in the following expression:
( B^ν d^μ Subscript[B, ν] Subscript[d, μ] + 
   B^μ d^ν Subscript[B, ν] Subscript[d, μ] + 
   d^ν x^aμ Subscript[B, ν] Subscript[d, μ] - 
   d^μ x^aν Subscript[B, ν] Subscript[
    d, μ]) /. {B^ν d^μ Subscript[B, ν] Subscript[
     d, μ] + 
    B^μ d^ν Subscript[B, ν] Subscript[d, μ] -> 
   B^μν Subscript[B, ν] Subscript[d, μ], 
  d^ν x^aμ Subscript[B, ν] Subscript[d, μ] - 
    d^μ x^aν Subscript[B, ν] Subscript[d, μ] -> 
   Subscript[B, ν] Subscript[d, μ] X^aμν}


Use ReplaceRepeated (//.) instead of ReplaceAll (/.).
Let me use a simpler example with the same algebraic structure as in your expression:
a + b + c - d /. {a + b -> A, c - d -> B}
(* A + c - d *)

a + b + c - d //. {a + b -> A, c - d -> B}
(* A + B *)

The reason that ReplaceAll does not do what you expect is explained in the documentation:

ReplaceAll looks at each part of expr, tries all the rules on it, and then goes on to the next part of expr. The first rule that applies to a particular part is used; no further rules are tried on that part or on any of its subparts.

Once the first rule is matched against the the Plus in Plus[a,b,c,Times[-1,d]], it will not consider any other rules on other parts of the Plus. Another simple example to illustrate this:
a + b + f /. {a + b -> A, f -> F}
(* A + f *)


A similar answer is given by Carl Woll on an older question about Not all rules being used in replacement.

This seems to be a bug in ReplaceAll.
ReplaceAll is supposed to work for any head of an expression. However, if the head is "Plus" you got the above error:

However, if you put the first 2 terms and the next 2 terms in a list like:

it seems to work as expected.
I think this should be reported to: support@wolfram.com

I can't understand why this was down-voted, without comment.

I don't think this is a bug, but a consequence of the first bullet point in ReplaceAll. (I didn't down-vote, though :))
